# R: Plotting with ggplot using multiple lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

so I'm trying to Plot `chart`. I filtered the original dataset `Datengf` to get the median income of each year (`MULTYEAR`) and the variable `Schulbildung`. No chart looks like this: [chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRjrl.png). Now I want to plot `chart` by using `ggplot` and `geom_line`. On the x-axis `MULTYEAR` and on the y-axis the `medianincome`. But I want it to be a different line and color for each value of `Schulbildung`.

Chart code:

```
chart <- Datengf %>%
  filter(SEX == 1)%>%
  group_by(MULTYEAR,Schulbildung) %>% 
  summarise(medianincome = median(INCWAGE))%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  mutate(Schulbildung = ifelse(Schulbildung < 12, "others", Schulbildung)) %>%
  group_by(Schulbildung,MULTYEAR)%>%
  summarise(medianincome = sum(medianincome))
```

I tried using

```
chartplot <- chart %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = MULTYEAR, y = medianincome))+
     geom_line()
```

but the chart is an complete mess.

Comment: You probably need `colour = Schulbildung` inside `aes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify `color` in the `aes` function:

```
chartplot <- chart %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = MULTYEAR, y = medianincome, color = Schulbildung))+
     geom_line()
```